# How do Rodenstock polarizer filters compare to B+W, Heliopan, and Hoya HD?

Tags: filters, polarizer

I am looking for a good polarizer filter for my 67mm thread lens. I have good experience with the Hoya 8Layer HD cir-pol filter and I really like that it is not as dark as other filters, but it is very expensive and according to reviews it is not as "clean" across the wavelengths and the surface as others like B+W and Heliopan.

http://www.lenstip.com/115.1-article-Polarizing_filters_test.html

http://www.lenstip.com/index.php?art=119

I have come across the Rodenstock filters, but I cannot find any reviews.
They are well known for their glasses, so they should be capable of making good camera filters as well?

I value non-filtered transmission (the T1 curve in the tests) and anti glare coating highest in my selection of the filter.

Comment: The only Rodenstock filters I ever used were degrading filters for Grandagon lenses (they call them *center filters* now for marketing reasons — seems some folks took the term *degrading* to mean something other than intended), and while they were very good, there is also a "no choice" element with them (they're matched to the lens) so there was no way to compare across brands. My Schneiders would only work properly on Schneider lenses, and my Rodenstocks on Rodenstocks.

Comment: Well, I read an informal description of the HR version here:

http://mediadesigner.digitalmedianet.com/articles/viewarticle.jsp?id=181479

and it looks promising and they are "for everyone". But it is the "standard" version I consider as it is the same price range as Hoya HD and B&W kaesemann.

Comment: Seems to get a good coating I'd need the HR version, which has a 8 layer coating like the Hoya HD, and it has the brass ring like the B+W and Heliopan. That is spec-wise comparison. The standard version should compare to Hoya/Kenko Pro1.

Comment: Singh-Ray are very popular and high quality, have you checked them out?

Comment: now I have and they seem to be on the bottom quality wise with tiffen.

Comment: What kind of filter are you looking for?  C-pol? UV? Center?

Comment: I tagged polarizer for a reason ;p

Comment: Stay with Hoya HD, it's the best money can buy. I have used dozens of filters from various brands and there is nothing that compares to Hoya high-end ones, I am currently using HD2 whenever it's available. Stay away from B+W, the color-shifts so bad, I feel nauseated when looking through the viewfinder with them.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that Rodenstock, Heliopan and B+W are of the same quality and Hoya is one grade lower. They are mostly in same price range also.

I have like 6-7 good quality filters and they are mostly B+W, just one of them is Formatt.

Some  reviews about Rodenstock says it creates a blue vignetting. I have a B+W [B+W 77mm Kaesemann Circular Polarizer MRC Filter](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/10889-REG/B_W_66_045620_77mm_Kaeseman_Circular_Polarizing.html) and it's perfect. I didn't have any problems with it. No vignetting and it comes with a solid case. It also got 4.7 points out of 5 from 208 reviews which you may also read on BH Photo.

Rodenstock has no reviews at BH photo at the time. So I suggest bet on a well-known filter rather than an unpopular.

B+W also has a MRC Multi-Resistant Coating which reduces ghosting, flaring and haze. It's made of high quality Schott Glass.

Comment: I havent noticed this answer till now. You say some reviews on rodenstock mention blue vignetting, where are these reviews? Later you say rodenstock has none. So is it B+W that has blue vig?

Comment: I corrected it, added "no reviews at BH photo at the time". Those other reviews I mentioned were what I found on Google. Some people say Rodenstock has a blue vignetting on google. I don't have this issue with B+W so you can go with it too in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a good filter for my 67mm thread lens. I have good
>   experience with the Hoya 8Layer HD cir-pol filter and I really like
>   that it is not as dark as other filters, but it is very expensive and
>   according to reviews it is not as "clean" across the wavelengths and
>   the surface as others like B+W and Heliopan.

I did my own [quick comparison between B+W and Hoya HD](http://www.elsners.org/polarizer-filter-mini-test-2/) once and I found that the Hoya HDs had greenish or yellowish tint and B+Ws were more neutral. The Hoya is worth it if you need the better light transmission. B+Ws are my personal choice going forward.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using some of the said filters E.g. Hoya, Nikon B+Ws filters.  I use Rodenstock filter only on my beat and most expensive lenses Nikon f1.4 gold ring lenses, Canon f1.4 L lenses and Zeiss Batis on Sony alphas.  I can tell you, forget about little reviews BHPhoto.  The little reviews are all 5 stars.  I have only good thing to speak of the Rodenstock filters.  Believe me, they are second to none

Comment: What good things _do_ you have to say?